# MDrivenTurnkeyCore on Ubuntu with .net core

Tags: mdriven

"dotnet exec StreaminAppCoreWebApp.dll" works on Windows but not on Ubuntu with .net core. Do you have plans to make it run on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are aiming for a complete turnkey core to run on all the platforms where .net core is available. We prioritize based on client demands and this is currently NOT on the top of the list -> no date set.